# How to improve a python regex data file parsing efficiency?

Tags: python, regex, performance

I have data files like this:

```
group Head:
  data1:        abc         data2:            def
  2word data3:  ghi         data4:            jkl
  data3:        mno         three word data4: pqr stu
```

So in python i built a regex expression like this:

```
Data = re.findall(r'(([\w\(\)]+[ \t\f]?)+):([ \t\f]*(\S+))', data)
```

My files are near 600 lines, often with 2 columns as shown above, and parsing them takes several minutes per file.

What would be the best way to make this code more efficient so it can run in less than 10 seconds per file?

Comment: What are you trying to extract from these files?

Comment: Can you provide the grammar describing this format?

Comment: @Floris the keys and the values, but the whole file in the format listed above just the important parts are.  For example i want the key 'data1' and the value 'abc'

Comment: Is the key "the string without spaces immediately preceding the first colon in the line"? And is the value "the first word after that"? In other words - what output do you want for line 2, line 3? Does it have to be Python regex?

Comment: @Lucho these files are just plain text files, output from networking devices.  This is data extracted from pollers

Comment: The regex above produces `('data1', 'data1', ' abc', 'abc')` for example. Why?

Comment: @Floris Yes, the string before the colon but not if there is more than 1 space since you dont want the result from column 1. And then the value after the colon.  for line 2 '2word data3'=>'ghi', 'data4'=>'jkl'.  Unfortunately i only have python and php at my disposal in this environment

Comment: So you do want to return `2word data3` in its entirety as a key... and also `three word data4` - right? Anything separated by no more than a single space is part of the key. Could it be done in more than one pass?

Comment: @Floris yes whatever is most efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

data = """group Head:
  data1: abc         data2: def
  2word data3: ghi   data4: jkl
  data3: mno         three word data4: pqr stu"""

for l in data.split('\n'):
    print [ x.split(':') for x in re.split('\s\s+', l) if x ]
```

Gives:

```
[['group Head', '']]
[['data1', ' abc'], ['data2', ' def']]
[['2word data3', ' ghi'], ['data4', ' jkl']]
[['data3', ' mno'], ['three word data4', ' pqr stu']]
```

Comment: I am going to bet that this is significantly faster because it processes one line at a time, instead of the entire file.

Comment: @perreal Thank you! It now executes less then 2 seconds per file!  Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're nesting repetition operators and might be getting [exponential backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Try this instead:

```
r'(\S.+)\s*:\s*(\S+)'
```

Non-whitespace followed by anything else, a colon with optional whitespace around it, and some more non-whitespace.

Comment: +1 I think you are correct about the exponential backtracking, thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

This might take a shorter time

```
 # ([\w()](?:[^\S\r\n]?[\w()]+)*)[^\S\r\n]*:[^\S\r\n]*([\w()](?:[^\S\r\n]?[\w()]+)*)

 (                                 # (1) Key
      [\w()] 
      (?: [^\S\r\n]? [\w()]+ )*
 )
 [^\S\r\n]* : [^\S\r\n]* 
 (                                 # (2) Value
      [\w()] 
      (?: [^\S\r\n]? [\w()]+ )*
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-compile your regex. [Docs.](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.compile)

If possible, split your files and parse line by line.

Both should help reduce your times.

Comment: the `re` module already caches recent regexes; this shouldn't save _minutes_ unless there are hundreds of regexes floating around